# Avoid inserting duplicate nodes, Neo4j using Java

Tags: java, neo4j, duplicates, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to add some nodes to my Neo4j Graph database using Java like so:

```
Node basketCourt = graphDatabaseService.createNode(Labels.COURT);
Node playerNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(Labels.PLAYER);
playerNode.setProperty("name", player.getName());
Relationship relation = playerNode.createRelationshipTo(basketCourt, RelTypes.PLAYS);
```

My graph database can reach up to one million nodes.
I don't want the graph to contain duplicate nodes. For instance i do not want to have more than one playerNode with the name "Micheal Jordan". Using "findNode(Label, String, Object)" to check if the node is already in the database before inserting it takes too much time since I have millions of nodes.

I am looking for something like "Merge" in Cypher where it matches the pattern or create it if it does not exist. But i want to insert nodes using Java and not Cypher. Is there a way to do so? Maybe something I can configure to avoid duplicates? Or something that Neo4j has thought of and provided a solution to my problem?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you looked at https://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create-with-factory

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is very helpful !

Comment: You are Welcome, once done would you mind putting in your own solution in the answer.

Comment: I did not wrote down a solution yet, I will post it when I do. But i will basically use UniqueFactory and the getOrCreateWithOutcome method  that "Get the indexed entity, creating it (exactly once) if no indexed entity exists. Includes the outcome, i.e. whether the entity was created or not." And to check if the node was already present i will use the wasCreated() methode